# Raspberry Pi Camera Module distorted colours

Tags: hardware, raspicam, image

I've been using the same camera module for a long time without realizing some colours seem to be very off. For instance black seems to turn purple or red (see picture below). Is there any settings I have to change or is the camera broken? I remember seeing this colour distortion ever since I bought it.

image taken from RPi (black turns purple, colours are incorrect)
[image: image taken from RPi (black turns purple, colours are incorrect)]

image taken from my phone (here the colours are correct)
[image: image taken from my phone (here the colours are correct)]

Any ideas as to why the colours are off would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably using NO IR camera and since there's no IR filter you see black as purple.